# How to rearrange cells for UILocalNotification tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, cell

A group of programmers I work with and I have a storyboard with a TableViewController that shows a list of UILocalNotifications that we have coded from a date picker. They all have different times and the timestamp shows up in the tableview cell each time the reminder is set along with the reminder text. At present, the reminders show up in chronological order (the order in which they were set). The cells with old reminders are automatically cleared once the localNotification has been fired. So far, all of this has been successful.

The issue lies with the last small function. As the reminders app that is being made is designed to be customisable, we want the user to be able to move the cells around. We have been successful as  a group at allowing for the user to edit the order, however face another dilemma. Once the order has been changed and the user leaves the view (the app is navigation bar based) and returns to the view, the order has defaulted back to the original as opposed to the customised order that they entered from moving cells.

So, here is the question (and hopefully my code below for how we are entering data in the tableview will provide some context). My group is wondering, how do we save and load the position of the user modified cells in the table based on the list. As you may notice in our code, the list of reminders is purely chronological just by calling upon the UILocalNotification class. Should we get the parameters of each individual cell and save them to an array, then load them somehow? Feedback on this issue would be greatly appreciated. I have also provided several screenshots that should hopefully give you a sense of what is happening on the end user side of things.

We as a group have entered the parameter for editing as follows:

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
```

We also have the following to allow for moving of table cells:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```

to support rearranging the tableview cells. Is this the best method to enter code for saving positions? Is there any property of a UITableView that can save and load the state of the table? Also, if we need to get the local notifications into the form of strings, what would be the syntax for doing so? << These subquestions should guide the original question which I found difficult to phrase.

This is how the information is entered into the tableview. A few applicable annotations have been added.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier        forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // Get list of local notifications
    NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Display notification info
    NSDate *date = localNotification.fireDate;

     NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
     NSString *dateFormatter = [formatter1 stringFromDate:date];

     NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"EEEE hh:mm"];
     NSString *dateFormatter2 = [formatter2 stringFromDate:date];

     NSString *on = [dateFormatter2 stringByAppendingString:@" on the "];
     NSString *final = [on stringByAppendingString:dateFormatter];

     [cell.textLabel setText:localNotification.alertBody];

     if (final.length != 8) {
          [cell.detailTextLabel setText:final];
     }
     else {
          [cell.detailTextLabel setText:@""];
     }

return cell;
```

}

In terms of screenshots of the app. This is what we have. We have an edit parameter and the cells set up inside a tableviewcontoller with a navigation bar. The main view (as seen in the upper most screenshot) is where text is entered. This is then entered as a UIlocalnotification when a date picker date (or preset) is selected

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you for taking the time to respond to this question.

Comment: from where you are getting information for tableview(are you using DB)

Comment: I am getting it from date picker.date (in a view not shown) and taking the text entered from the textField. This is then saved as a local notification array with time and text.

Comment: Than you need to re-arrange your array(local notification array) while you rearrange he cells. statement should be like .. i'll show it in answer please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{

 NSString * firstObject = localnotificationarray[fromIndexPath];
 [localnotificationarray replaceObjectAtIndex: fromIndexPath withObject:localnotificationarray[toIndexPath]];
 [localnotificationarray replaceObjectAtIndex: toIndexPath withObject: firstObject];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are loading the array from UIApplication before view gets loaded and hence whatever changes you have done after rearranging the array is lost. I suggest you save the rearranged array back in this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{

// rearrange arrayNotifications

// then set it to [UIApplication sharedApplication] again
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setScheduledLocalNotifications:arrayNotifications];

}
```